# Ajax form works on page but not on block

Tags: ajax, drupal

I have a module that builds a form that uses ajax.

If if i create a page with hook_menu() to show the form with, all is well.. ajax is working, etc.

```
function models_quicksearch_menu() {
$items = array();

  // Repopulate a dropdown based on form state.
  $items['examplex_dropdown'] = array(
    'title' => 'Dependent dropdown',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('quicksearch_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'weight' => 4,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

If i create a block to show the form the ajax part of the form doesn't work:

```
function models_quicksearch_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'quicksearch_form':
  $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('quicksearch_form');
  break;
}
return $block;
}
```

The ajax.js didn't load at first when i've used the block method so i've loaded the js's:

```
function models_quicksearch_process(&$variables, $hook) {
    drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');
    drupal_add_library('system', 'jquery.form');
}
```

but still, if i use the block method the ajax part does not work. And it seems the "ajax-processed" class is missing from the form element in the block version. In the 'page' version "ajax-processed" is there.

I'm using Drupal 7.

Any idea on how to solve this ? 
Thank you.

EDIT: 
It seems that the problem was that i was printing the block directly in html.tpl.php. If i print it in page.tpl.php it works just fine.